# Git checkout a revision without deleting unaffected files

Tags: git

I want to revert to a previous revision without deleting files, a visual representation of this would be:

3 files;

```
myfile
mysecondfile
mythirdfile
```

Now this is currently `origin/master` and my working copy.

What I want to do is revert to a previous revision, lets say `DEADBEEF`,

`DEADBEEF` revision only has one file;

```
myfile
```

What I want to do is overwrite my local `myfile` with the previous revision without deleting `mysecondfile` or `mythirdfile`.

Comment: `git checkout DEADBEEF -- myfile`

Comment: that would be fine but the name of the files are dynamic, I was just using names for clarity on my issue :p

Comment: You're saying that file creation doesn't affect the file which is being created?

Comment: @RobertPounder what do you mean the name of the files is "dynamic" ? How do you determine the files you want to keep at version `DEADBEEF`, and and the files to be at version `origin/master` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Solution first

If you have the possibility to use the `xargs` command line command that is an easy task.

```
$ git ls-tree --name-only -r <tree-ish> . | xargs git checkout <tree-ish> --
```

#### Breakdown of commands used

- [`git ls-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree) will list the content of a tree object
  This means it will show all the files that were present in the repository at a certain commit

  - `--name-only` will restrict the output to the (relative, use `--full-name` for absolute paths) path of the files
  - `-r` will show all files recursively
- `|` will pipe the output of one command to the next
- `xargs` is used here to give the result of `ls-tree` as arguments to `git checkout`
- [`git checkout <tree-ish> --`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_argument_disambiguation) will (in this form) checkout files from the given `tree-ish` without changing branches

#### Bonus: Show what you changed in those files

To view the changes that you did since `<tree-ish>` use:

```
$ git diff --staged -R
```

If the command is used without `-R` you would see the changes as if you changed everything **to** the old state.

Answer (score 3):

To create a new commit with the content of an old commit (and your current files), try a combination of [`git read-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree), [`git checkout-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout-index) and [`git update-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index):

```
git read-tree DEADBEEF 
git checkout-index -f -a
git update-index -q --refresh
```

Then commit.

---

Meaning: no need to use shell trick with `xargs`: git has the tools you need.

- `git read-tree DEADBEEF` will restore the index from that old commit (which will make all other files "untracked" or "modified", since they were not part of that old commit `DEADBEEF`)
- `git checkout-index -f -a` will force the working tree to reflect that index (again, without modifying the files which were not part of the index)
- `git update-index -q --refresh` will make sure index and working tree are in sync.

Finally add and commit: you will get all your other files plus the content of the old commit.

Comment: This is also a nice solution, sorry I can't give bounty twice :(

Comment: @RobertPounder no problem. I just don't understand the one you have chosen.

Comment: I tried it and it suits my needs, I tried this after and it also does what I need, also the explanation that didn't require me to change sites helped him get the bounty for future reference

Answer (score 2):

For the situation you've given there, the command is

```
git checkout deadbeef -- .
```

which resets every file in commit deadbeef to its contents as of that commit.

Answer (score -1):

If mr_sudaca's answer doesn't satisfy your desire I'm afraid there's no such possibility in git.

If you want your master HEAD to be pointed to *myfile* previous revision and keep *mysecondfile* and *mythirdfile* current state - just make it the git way, clear and easy:

1. Save *mysecondfile* and *mythirdfile* somewhere.
2. Run git revert [you latest commit sha-1] (sha-1 could be found by git log)
3. Copy *mysecondfile* and *mythirdfile* back then make a new commit.

Comment: you've posted a less optimised version of mr_sudaca's solution, if you don't know a way I'm wondering why you've posted this as an answer?

Comment: @Robert Pounder because I know there's no way

Comment: There is plenty of ways and I'm open to suggestions of a good practice for it as I can not think of one...

Comment: @RobertPounder: so you insist that there are plenty of ways (how many is "plenty"? 3? 50?) even though you know of none? I'm sure there are some ways, but perhaps you should offer a few of your own ideas to start with, here.  (I'd suggest you either abandon the notion of running `git checkout`, or use one Git-managed work-tree and a completely separate non-Git-managed tree to hold your union-of-files.)

Comment: see the question @torek `I want to revert to a previous revision without deleting files` there are plenty of ways manually that can be converted to a programmatic process

Comment: @Robert Pounder What I meant to say by my answer and further comment is: "Git has no special command to perform such action". Git has rich set of basis commands. I almost sure you can find a few different packs of commands, but you're not gonna find one command that would be a solution. Perhaps there are better ways to do that, I'm not sure my answer is the best. But it's clear and it solves your problem

Comment: @SergeyVoitovich I'm just trying to think of better ways to go about it like maybe creating a temporary branch with the extra files before reverting, (which is probably what I will do)

Comment: While there may or may not be other ways, the method suggested by @SergeyVoitovich is almost certainly the easiest.  It's unlikely you'll hit a situation like this again, why spend hours trying to find the "right" way when you can just solve it quickly using this method?

Comment: @taylorc93 thats the issue, I WILL be hitting this situation again ...the whole point of making a programmatic approach to this.